# jQuery on click doesn't recognize child-div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, onclick

I'm using jQuery's on click to bind click to a dynamically added div with the class coda-nav-left-arrow.

```
$('#slider-wrap').on('click', '.coda-nav-left-arrow', function () {
    alert(countClicks);
});
```

The problem is, this generated div is the child of another generated div, so it's not directly below the #slider-wrap div:

```
<div id="slider-wrap">
  <div id="slider-id-wrapper" class="coda-slider-wrapper arrows">
    <div class="coda-nav-left-arrow">
```

This is why (I think) jQuery doesn't recognize it. Is my assumption correct? How can I make it visible?

**Edit:** Just to be clear, the #slider-wrap div exists from the very beginning. This is not dynamically generated. Everything else is.

**Edit2 (Solved):** This is sufficient for the code to work:

```
$('.coda-nav-left-arrow').on('click',function(){});
```

As long as it is enclosed in the

```
$(document).ready(function(){}
```

block.

**Edit 3:** So we learned that .on() goes multiple levels deep and that it only works when the document is ready.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$('.coda-nav-left-arrow').on('click', function({}))`?

Comment: If `#slider-wrap` is not a static element, you are not delegating the event, you should choose a static parent element or document object.

Comment: @nicooga That doesn't delegate the event.

Comment: Then what I am missing here with this example? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Fr3t/)

Comment: I was wrong. This is really working the way you posted it! The reason it didn't work before is because I didn't enclose it in the $(document).ready(function(){} block. Thank you! Could you post this as answer to get all the upvotes? ;)

Comment: well, IF `.coda-nav-left-arrow` is a dynamically added div then the solution (`$('.coda-nav-left-arrow').on('click',function(){});`) doesn't work, even if it is wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` ... see my **[forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtGeY/6/)** ... it will only work for existing elements. You still need to delegate for dynamically added elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="btn">Do Something</button>​
```

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $('body').prepend($('<button>').attr('id', 'foo').html('I\'m a foo doer'));
  return $('#foo').on('click', function() {
    return alert("Foo thing");
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Fr3t/)

Comment: @Cos : if this is the correct answer, then I didn't understand the question :(

Comment: It's a generalization about how to bind events to dynamically generated HTML elements.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have attached the handler to `#slider-wrap` when it's is in the DOM?

Try wrapping in [jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#slider-wrap').on('click', '.coda-nav-left-arrow', function () {
        alert(countClicks);
    });
});
```

Or add the script code after the div is created:

```
<div id="slider-wrap">
  <div id="slider-id-wrapper" class="coda-slider-wrapper arrows">
    <div class="coda-nav-left-arrow">
    ....
  ....
</div> <!-- end of #slider-wrap -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#slider-wrap').on('click', '.coda-nav-left-arrow', function () {
        alert(countClicks);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it doesn't really matter placing the script before or after since the delegation via `.on()` will affect to existing and/or future descendant elements : [...Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time....](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @JFK what im saying is that the `<div id="slider-wrap">` needs to be in the DOM before the event gets attached. Not that we have to attach the event after the `<div class="coda-nav-left-arrow">` get created.

Comment: my comment was in regard of your statement `Or add the script code after the div is created:` ... it can be after or before, doesn't really matter

Comment: @JFK if the script block is before the `<div id="slider-wrap">` it's isn't yet created in the DOM and then the selector `#slider-wrap` returns ~ `$(null)`. Note the difference between the two code blocs: The first one is wrapped in `jQuery.ready` and the second one isn't.

Comment: if you read the question carefully, `#slider-wrap` does exist. It is the child container `#slider-id-wrapper` as well as `.coda-nav-left-arrow` that are dynamically added.

Comment: @JFK I can see that `#slider-wrap` indeed exists. But it doesn't before the DOM is ready. As you can see here: http://jsbin.com/ibevah/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.coda-nav-left-arrow', function () {
    alert(countClicks);
});
```

Comment: You should try avoiding global event handlers. This will work, but you should just use 1 parent above instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfectly fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider-wrap').on('click', '.coda-nav-left-arrow', function () {
        alert(countClicks);
    });
});
```

... [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgwmS/).

The delegation doesn't affect to the immediate children only but to all down levels. You may have another js or syntax error that breaks this particular code (but hard to say without a link)

Comment: Hmm, good to know, thank you. I can't provide a link because I only have it locally right now. But I'll check all the JS again...

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a parent element to delegate to. You need to select an element that does exist. Try not to do `body` or `document` tho if there is a parent to `#slider-wrap`.

The alternative which I'd suggest is attaching the the event while creating the element dynamically like:

```
var $sliderWrap = $('<div id="slider-wrap">{YOUR OTHER HTML HERE}</div>');
$sliderWrap.on('click', '.coda-nav-left-arrow',function(){
  alert(countClicks);
});
$sliderWrap.appendTo('body');
```

I also suggest reading up on event delegation so you understand what jQuery is doing behind the scenes. It's not too complicated:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it ok to attach event handlers to `document` element because it is always available ? Doesn't it affect performance in some way ? Shouldn't this be done for the most close parent element if available ?

Comment: @Oscar Godson: the #slider-wrap element does exist from the very beginning.

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko Yes, it does and you should avoid it. See my comment on Dom's post.

Comment: @Cos Are your JS script tags not at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @OscarGodson they were. Please see my edit, the question is solved.

Comment: @Cos you only need the document ready if your JS is code comes before the DOM. Example: http://jsbin.com/exiraj/1/edit -- Make sure you're loading all your JS at the bottom of the body. You won't need document ready then.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528198/jquery-is-document-ready-necessary